# How to replace single space to multiple space?

Tags: java

There are functions available for multiple spaces to single space, but I want to add more spaces where single spaces are there.

I tried this:

```
int rem = b - temp.length();
for(int k = 0; k < rem; k++) {
    temp.replace(" ", "  ");
}
```

I want to add that much space between words as predefined length of string.

Comment: You have provided incomplete information. What is `b`? What goes wrong with the code snippet you shared?

Comment: temp = temp.replace(" ","   "), Once you replace you need to assign to temp again

Comment: b is predefined length of string . @SujeetSinha

Answer (score 2):

You only need to invoke `temp.replace(" ","  ");` once (i.e. instead of looping) to replace all single spaces with two consecutive spaces.

However, since `String`s are immutable, you need to *assign* `temp` with the outcome of your `replace` invocation.

```
temp = temp.replace(" ","  ");
```

Comment: But i want that much space that i need if there are 10 single space and max space i want 15 then i cant use it it will create 10 more space that ll overflow of space.

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you a combination of String.trim Method and REGEX

## EXAMPLE:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String temp = "Is      you       see this      is    because   ";
    String replacedString = temp.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
    System.out.println(temp);
    System.out.println(replacedString);
}
```

this will correct the temp String to

> Is you see this is because